# What common methods are employed to separate data storage from algorithms?

Tags: oop

Say you store all your data in a class, like`KittenStorage`. You then have a class that wants to find a specific color kitten, probably called `KittenFinder`. Obviously, you have designed your object oriented program to separate these two distinctly different classed, but now `KittenFinder` needs to directly interact with `KittenStorage`. How do you connect these two different classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends, some would put a Find Method on KittenStorage that returned a kitten.

Assuming KittenStorage is a Store for Kittens
And KittenFinder is a Finder for a Kittens or Kittens(s) in a KittenStorage

And that Kitten is a Storable and Findable Item
That also has some behaviours e.g. Scratch, that are nothing todo with it being storable and Findable, then Kitten would be linked to KittenStorage by IStorable, and KittenFinder to KittenStorage by IFindable

There's also a good reason to have a DTO (Data Transfer Object). Which would be simply Kitten's state, ie what you are finding and storing aren't Kitten's that scratch

Basically all the above is making the assumption that there's also a PuppyStorage and PuppyFinder etc, and that you want to be as decoupled as you can.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use layers. First of all, you need a Data Access Layer. This layer will contain classes which support direct data storage commands. Next, you need a Business Layer. This Layer performs anything needed to be performed in your business logic. This layer will use the data storage via the Data Access Layer. Optionally you can create an Engine Layer where some more complex algorithms might be implemented, which will communicate with the data storage via the business layer. Finally, you have the UI, which will communicate with your data storage through the Engine Layer or the Business Layer. In real-life your storage is a database and your Data Access Layer communicates with the database. I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Lets evolve your example a bit - lets say that KittenStorage gives you a indexed access to the kittens in the form of storage.get(0) or storage[0], and that it also has a count or size property toknow how many kittens it stores.
This way KittenFinder can be implemented to do forward search i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < storege.size; i++)
{
     //return kitten if matches
}
```

or it can do a [BinarySearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search)

Also the KittenStorage class may include an persistence mechanism (like saving kittens to DB, or file). Maybe it can contain a perisitance strategy - a different class so that persistence mechanism could be swapped.

This is called Separation of Concerns - A class should do only one thing and only in one way - this way it's easy to maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, KittenFinder has a "dependency" on KittenStorage. Your question is how to set (inject) this dependency. That goes to your choice of application framework. Spring framework is one popular way of doing this.